# Converting Count of Rows into Column Format in Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
VID RS
1   A
1   B
1   B
2   C
2   A
```

what I want to do is to calculate the count of each RS for each VID and want to have an output as follows:

```
VID A   B   C
1   1   2   0
2   1   0   1
```

Is it possible to do through a query or I need to create temp table and perform insert/update on that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your number of `RS` is fixed then you can do

```
select vid, 
       sum(case when RS = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) AS A,
       sum(case when RS = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) AS B,
       sum(case when RS = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) AS C
from your_table
group by vid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways

One is use [**`Pivot`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable
       PIVOT (Count(rs)
             FOR rs IN([A],
                       [B],
                       [C]) )piv
```

**Note :**
If your `RS` column values are not `static` then convert the pivot to `Dynamic Pivot`

Another way is use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT vid,
       Count(CASE Rs WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END) [A],
       Count(CASE Rs WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END) [B],
       Count(CASE Rs WHEN 'C' THEN 1 END) [C]
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY vid
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8197c/1)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the pivot command on msdn which will do just that.

Update:

For this example:

```
SELECT Vid,
       [A] AS 'A',
       [B] AS 'B',
       [C] AS 'C'
FROM   your_table
       PIVOT (Count(RS)
             FOR RS IN( [A],
                        [B],
                        [C])) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: That should rather be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in `RS` is dynamic, you should chose `dynamic pivot`.

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 VID,   'A' RS
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,   'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,   'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,   'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,   'A'
)TAB
```

**QUERY**

Declare two variables to get columns for pivot and replace `NULL` with zero

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + RS + ']','[' + RS + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT RS FROM #TEMP) PV  
               ORDER BY RS

DECLARE @NullToZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',ISNULL(['+RS+'],0) AS ['+RS+']' 
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT RS FROM #TEMP GROUP BY RS)TAB  
ORDER BY RS  FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)
```

Now take the count and pivot

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '
             SELECT VID,' + @NullToZeroCols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT VID,RS,COUNT(RS)OVER(PARTITION BY VID,RS)CNT
                 FROM #TEMP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CNT)
                 FOR RS IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8705c/1)**